# NSViewController-Close window-Swift-Storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

I cannot find the right way to close the main window after I clicked the "proceed" button installed on this window.
I have try to connect this button to the "proceedclose" option of the inspector. 
I have also try to insert the following line inside my code :

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    ...
    @IBAction func Envoi(sender: NSButton) {    
        self.view.window!.close()
    }
}
```

None of them works, nothing happens and no error is reported.
Could anyone help me to sort it out?

Comment: I checked the "release when closed" option inside IB but still the same.

Comment: It is working by using "self.view.window!.close()" inside the button action, but when I add a new ViewController, and link the button to it, the first window does not disappear anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same question. And your code was very helpful for me.

Then I checked "VC <- view <- window <- windowController" out in NS Lib. hierarchey has.

When you close window from VC, avoiding storyboard grow bizzare.
you can solve this, by

```
self.view.window?.windowController?.close()
```

Just a quick note.

Comment: windowController doesn't have `close()` method

Comment: I realized finally that this problem is related to the use of UIElement (StatusBar). "self.view.window?.windowController?.close()" is working but as soon as I change the "Application is agent" option to "yes", the frame of the Main window is disapearing but a white rectangle remains.

Answer (score 6):

1. Be aware of each `NSViewController` and `NSButton` instance.  Fix management of `NSViewController` and `NSButton` instances if needed.

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var envoiButton: NSButton!
    //…
    @IBAction func doEnvoiButtonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {    
        print(self.hash)
        print(self.envoiButton.hash)
        // … other code
    }
}
```

2. Set `isReleasedWhenClosed` in either the Interface Builder or in code, if needed.
3. Closed the window via the `NSButton` `@IBAction` (e.g. Envoi) with one of the following

- **`self.view.window!.windowController!.close()`** [NSWindowController close()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1535390-close) *abrupt close without possibility to ask user for confirmation.*
- **`self.view.window!.close()`** [NSWindow close()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419662-close)
  *sends `willCloseNotification` notification*.
- **`self.view.window!.performClose(nil)`** or **`self.view.window!.performClose(self)`** [NSWindow performClose(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419288-performclose) *sends to all window closing signals. First, `windowShouldClose(_:)` to window delegate if present. If no delegate is present, then invokes any NSWindow object `windowShouldClose(_:)` implementation. If `windowShouldClose(_:)` returns true or is not implemented, then `NSWindow close()` is called. **(`performClose(_:)` is the more comprehensive and flexible choice)***

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBAction func doEnvoiButtonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {    
        self.view.window!.performClose(nil) // or performClose(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: self.view.window!.performClose(nil)  works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

> It is working by using "self.view.window!.close()" inside the button action, but when I add a new ViewController, and link the button to it, the first window does not disappear anymore.

I'm assuming you may have forgotten to duplicate the `@IBAction func Envoi(sender: NSButton)` in the new ViewController? By doing this only your new window will close and not the first window.

Answer (score 0):

The following projet is dealing nicelly with this problem. Thanks to all of you for your answers.

https://www.appcoda.com/macos-status-bar-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add _ in front of sender and everything will work

```
import Cocoa
  class ViewController: NSViewController {
...
    @IBAction func Envoi(_ sender: NSButton) {    
        self.view.window!.close()
    }
  }
```